# node mean.io syntax what the purpose of expose app?

Tags: node.js

In the server.js file of mean.io 
I can see

```
//expose app
exports = module.exports = app;
```

Can anyone explain me the meaning,  what is it for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File in Question: https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/server.js

I would write something up, but I found [an article](http://fiveisprime.com/post/46947869653/exports-or-module-exports) that covers it nicely:

> [ . . . ] In [/src/node.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node.js) you can see that your
>   code is wrapped in a closure and passed both exports and module. Of
>   course, further inspection will show you that exports contains a
>   pointer to module.exports and suddenly everything makes sense.
>
> Overwriting exports overwrites the pointer to module.exports which
>   disconnects exports from the Node.js environment!
>
> What’s the point?
>
> Exports is a helper function that points to module.exports. This is
>   meant to make your life easier. That is all. Use it to expose
>   functions of your module, but if your module needs to replace what is
>   exposed, you must use module.exports.

Open up that article and take a look at the examples that are provided for more information.

---

In short, it's a way of making the app variable be referenced directly when it's required from another module instead of being nestled into an object, e.g.

```js
// hello.js
module.exports = 'hello';
```

```js
// foo.js
exports.foo = 'bar';
```

```js
// testing it out
console.log(require('hello.js')); // outputs 'hello'
console.log(require('foo.js')); // outputs { foo: 'bar' }
```